# Trying to map over state in useEffect function, but it mutates the state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have got the users listing by using redux-thunk, then I mapStateToProps those users to get them inside my props. But after that when I try to map over that props.users.users it changes my state (i.e. props.users.users gets changed even though I have used spread operator for the on that state). Please help with this.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    props.getUsers();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    let tempUsers = [...props.users.users];
    tempUsers = tempUsers.map(user => {
        user.created = new Date(parseInt(user.created) * 1000).toString()
        user.action = { ...user };
        return user;
    });
    setUsers(tempUsers);
}, [props.users.users]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still mutating the user objects in `map`. You are directly setting the properties of `user` object which are still referring to the original user object. You shoul create a new copy of `user` object too to set its properties.

```
tempUsers = tempUsers.map(usr => {
   let user = { ...usr };
   user.created = new Date(parseInt(user.created) * 1000).toString()
   user.action = { ...user };
   return user;
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot. that did the job. I was wondering from a long time what I was doing wrong but now its sorted. thank you very much.